How to share a variable (memory) between Powershell scripts?
Currently I have two Powershell scripts, main.ps1 and data.ps1, which share a global variable called $Global:SharedValues. The global variable is initialised in the data.ps1 script and is then used within the primary script, main.ps1. This all works perfectly.
However, the size of the script, data.ps1, is growing and it's maintenance is becoming less convenient, which is why I'd now like to split the contents up over multiple files. However, I'd like to be able to include the scripts dynamically so that I don't need to manually add a . include into the main.ps1 each time a new data script is created.
I have tried two approaches to dynamically include the scripts, Invoke-Expression $data and powershell.exe $data. In both cases the data scripts are run, however changes made to the global variable are ignored - so I gather the scripts are run in a separate memory instance!?
Is it possible to share the global variable between all the scripts? Can I somehow pass the variable via a pipeline or something to the dynamically included scripts?
Solution
Someone did provide an answer which I accepted, but it seems to have been removed now (I don't know why!?). The solution is quite simple; The . Dot-Source command can accept filenames via variables (which I didn't know). So, the solution was to use a Get-ChildItem to get a list of all the scripts I'd like to include and then simply Dot-Source them:
$Global:SharedValues = @{}
$dataScriptFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Filter "data-*"
foreach ( $file in $dataScriptFiles )
{
. $file.FullName # Dot-Source
}


You have the thought process correct, $global: is indeed the scope you use to share objects to your runspace memory.  Invoke-Expression runs inside the current runspace, so if it's using $global:, it should also be persistent.  But it sounds like you're using Invoke-Expression ./SomeFile.ps1?

Correct, Invoke-Expression $data where $data = "data.ps1" was one of the tests I tried, but it failed.
